# Can't solve scroll view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, scroll, scrollview

Could someone please explain to me how `ScrollView` works. How can I make that when I receive a message it scrolls to the last message ( item)?

I tried to make it with a `ScrollViewReader { proxy in }` but I still can't make this code work.

I tried also to make it `.onChange(of: ) { }` with `ScrollViewReader`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View{
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    @State var text = ""
    @State var models = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView (showsIndicators: false){
                    ForEach(models, id: \.self){ string in
                        Text(string)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color("Text"))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).strokeBorder(.blue, style: .init(lineWidth: 1))
                            )
                        Divider() 
                    }
                    .onChange(of: models){
                        proxy.scrollTo(models.last)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                TextField("Type here...", text: $text)
                    .padding(15.0)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Button() {
                    send()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Button"))
                }
                .padding(10.0)
            }
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                    .stroke(Color("Stroke"), lineWidth: 1)
            )
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.setup()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=View@*/Color("Background")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
    
    func send() {
        guard !text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        models.append("Me: \(self.text)")
        viewModel.send(text: text) { response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models.append("Answer: "+response)
                self.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code from when you used the ScrollViewReader? That is the way I would implement what you are trying to do, so I'm curious what you did and why it didn't work.

Comment: @fljbiz One idea before I hop into Xcode and play around myself. I think you need to explicitly define an id for the model you are scrolling to. `models.last` is just referring to the element, but the documentation seems to require an id. Try an explicit id for the model and reference that id.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different overload:

```swift
proxy.scrollTo(models.last,anchor:.top)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).